# Getting java.net.UnknownHostException: db-service" while calling db service

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

[server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sCJ0.png)

My stock-service client:

```
@Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

ResponseEntity<List<String>> quoteResponse =
    restTemplate.exchange("http://db-service/rest/db/" + userName, 
        HttpMethod.GET, 
        null, 
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {}
    );
```

Here db-service is registered service in eureka server.

Its working if i hit directly like

```
/* ResponseEntity<List<String>> quoteResponse =
    restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8300/rest/db/" + userName,
        HttpMethod.GET, 
        null, 
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {}
    );*/    

@Configuration

public class Config {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like All your local services are register with your local eureka. hence what you are trying achieve via `http://db-service/rest/db/ ` won't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand that db-service is your any micro-service and you want to send there request. You need to configure ribbon because `RestTemplate` doesn't understand `db-service` like host. You should add follow config:

```
db-service:
  ribbon:
    eureka:
      enabled: false
    listOfServers: localhost:8090
    ServerListRefreshInterval: 15000
```

and maven dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

or you could add Discovery service(Eureka) to your system and you don't need to describing `listOfSerevers` because ribbon will get all information from discovery service

Answer (score 0):

Please try by using `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client`.

And check the version of `spring-cloud-dependencies` along with `spring-boot-starter-parent` version.

`spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` should resolve the issue